# Google distance martix order by distance

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I fetchdata from https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=10010&destinations=10011|10012|10013&key=AIzaSyBOsjeskUwOLYQZntsv7_34gVZ3xgcXko0

it returns :

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [
      "New York, NY 10011, USA",
      "New York, NY 10012, USA",
      "New York, NY 10013, USA"
   ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "New York, NY 10010, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "3.4 km",
                  "value" : 3389
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "19 mins",
                  "value" : 1156
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "2.6 km",
                  "value" : 2632
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "13 mins",
                  "value" : 767
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "9.5 km",
                  "value" : 9545
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "19 mins",
                  "value" : 1143
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

But I need data order by distance. First showing small then large.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure! 
 1. Parse the JSON data to an object (JSON.parse); 
 2. Sort the elements array using code as below:

```
// given els is one of the elements extracted from this object: 
let sorted = els.sort((a, b) => a.distance.value - b.distance.value);
```